# How to reload a URL without refreshing the page in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to reload onto the same route without having to refresh the page. For this specific case, using `history.pushState()`, but I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: history.pushState is not a function.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Container } from 'kawax-js';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import File from './FileContainer';
import Folder from './FolderContainer';
import HomeContainer from './HomeContainer';

class RootContainer extends React.Component {

  static stateToProps = ({ ownProps, select }) => {
   const files = select('files');
   const lastFile =  _.last(files);
   return ({
    lastFile: lastFile || {}
 })
};

  static propTypes = {
   history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

  static defaultProps = {
   lastFile: {}
};

render() {
 const { lastFile, history } = this.props;
 if( lastFile === {} || !lastFile.isUploaded
  || lastFile.isUploaded === null) {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomeContainer} />
      <Route exact path="/file/:itemPath/:refHash" component={File} />
      <Route exact path="/:folderName" component ={Folder}/>
    </Switch>
   );
  }
  return history.pushState(null, "/:folderName")
 }
}

export default Container(RootContainer);
```

Is there a better way of doing this or am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing a refresh through history?

Answer (score 1):

You may get the desired result by forcing the component to rerender, take a look at the [documentation here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate). I see you are extending `React.Component` so you should be able to do the following:

```
...

constructor() {
    this.reload = this.reload.bind(this);
}

...

reload() {
   this.forceUpdate();
}

...
```

I know it does not use `history` but there will be no other code required as it is included with the `Component` class.

Answer (score 0):

please use this code
Router.browserHistory.push('/');
instaed of history.pushState(null, "/:folderName")

Comment: But this will just redirect me to my home page, I want it to just reload the page I am currently on.

Comment: then you put your current url after /

Comment: I tried that, but then I get `RootContainer(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.` I also tried `<Redirect to={location} component ={Folder}/>` , but in this case I get: `You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/test"`

Comment: try this one location.reload();

Comment: Tried it before :D that one actually refreshes the page which I do not want, I want to keep it single paged where nothing has to be refreshed. I am really losing my mind here...

Comment: use the following fomat                   window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", urlPath);       dont lose the hope

Comment: For a more in-depth look at manipulating browser history see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 0):

You have few possibilities to do that, currently my favorite way to do that is using anonymous function in component prop:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={()=><HomeContainer/>} />
  <Route exact path="/file/:itemPath/:refHash" component={()=><File/>} />
  <Route exact path="/:folderName" component ={()=><Folder/>}/>
</Switch>
```

Or if you want to refresh with current url params, you'll need extra route (reload), and play a little with router stack:

```
reload = ()=>{
 const current = props.location.pathname;
 this.props.history.replace(`/reload`);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.history.replace(current);
    });
}

<Switch>
  <Route path="/reload" component={null} key="reload" />
  <Route exact path="/" component={HomeContainer} />
  <Route exact path="/file/:itemPath/:refHash" component={File} />
  <Route exact path="/:folderName" component ={Folder}/>
</Switch>

<div onCLick={this.reload}>Reload</div>
```